# Bash mkdir and cd script returning error but still working

Tags: bash

For a while, I've had a need for a bash script to make a directory and cd into it. Most of the solutions online work but are very minimal so I wanted to make one that handles things like creating parent directories and permission checking. Here's my code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function mkcd() {

  # Check for no arguments
  if "$#" -eq 0; then
    echo "Error: no arguments provided"
    return 1
  fi

  # Checks if help flag is used
  # Not with other flags to ensure the directory isn't assumed to be a flag
  if [[ "$1" == "-h" || "$1" == "--help" ]]; then
    echo "mkcd - Makes a directory and changes directory to it\n"
    echo "Flags:"
    echo "    -h, --help           Display help message"
    echo "    -p, --parents        Makes parent directories as neeeded"
    echo "    -a, --absolute       Receive an absolute directory instead of relative\n"
    echo "Format: mkcd [arguments] directory"
    return 0
  fi

  # Flag checker
  while test "$#" -gt 1; do
    case "$1" in
    -p | --parents)
      mkcd_parents=true
      shift
      ;;
    -a | --absolute)
      shift
      ;;
    esac
  done

  mkcd_path="$1"

  if [[ ! -w "$PWD" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Permission denied"
    return 1
  fi

  if [[ -d "$mkcd_path" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Directory already exists"
    return 1
  fi

  if "$mkcd_parents"; then
    mkdir -p "$mkcd_path"
    cd "$mkcd_path"
  else
    mkdir "$mkcd_path"
    cd "$mkcd_path"
  fi
}
```

I also sourced it in my `.zshrc` file with `source ~/bin/*`

When I run the command, I get this output:

```
~ ❯ mkcd test_dir
mkcd:3: command not found: 1
mkcd:45: permission denied:
~/test_dir ❯
```

Does anyone understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Did you restart your shell after modifying .zshrc?

Comment: @jordanm yes, I've restarted every time before testing a change.

Comment: can you try `set -xv ; mkcd test_dir ; set +xv` to see if you can zero in on the line causing the problem?; if the directory already exists ... why not go ahead and `cd` to said directory instead of generating an error? personally, after checking for the existence of an arg I'd just `mkdir -p "$1"; cd "$1"`; add some intermediate error checking (`$?`) if you want, and you're done; also ... are you running under `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: How bout double quoting all variable refs?

Comment: @Roadowl I've updated the post to show it with double-quotes. It's now giving an extra error which I've also updated the post to show.

Comment: Shout-out to https://www.shellcheck.net/, which can help you easily catch these kinds of bugs.

Comment: @0x5453, though not this one, it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "$#" -eq 0; then
```

Since you have one argument to the script, that becomes after expansions

```
if 1 -eq 0; then
```

You probably meant to do

```
if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
```

instead. (With either of `[ .. ]` or `[[ .. ]]`.)

---

As an aside, I would change this

```
if "$mkcd_parents"; then
```

to

```
if [ "$mkcd_parents" = "true" ]; then
```

Otherwise if the `-p` option isn't given, `$mkcd_parents` is unset, `"$mkcd_parents"` expands to the empty string, and you get an error about that command not being found.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, I had to remove the double-quotes from some of the variables to resolve the other error I was receiving after trying to use them to see if that fixed it.

Comment: @actuallyatiger, hmm, where? I can't see where the quoting would be wrong in your code. (You use `[[ .. ]]` and that's one of the places where quoting variables _isn't_ really necessary, but it shouldn't do any harm either -- except at the right hand side of a pattern match or regex match.)

Comment: @ikkachu I did a bit more testing and realised that the error was coming from the `if "$mkcd_parents"; then` line, but then I saw your edit to your answer and that fixed it.

Comment: @actuallyatiger, ah yes. It seems you're right, `if $foo; then` does not give an error if `$foo` is empty. But I would avoid that anyway, since if you happen to end up with other garbage in the variable, it would be run as a command there... BTW, I only now noticed you were running Zsh; you had the question tagged with [bash] and have a `#!/bin/bash` hashbang in the script file. Probably doesn't matter much here, but in other cases would,  esp. with quoting/not quoting variables. Bash's error message for that `if "$foo"; then` isn't much better: `bash: : command not found`